# PHP Imap ignoring attachments from noreply emails

Tags: php, email, imap

My problem is simple, Im using the below code to read emails and download the attachments. This is not my code, I did not write it, its a generic imap reader I found online. The code somewhat works as it should seeing as I have no trouble reading my inbox and downloading the attachments as this code was written to do.

The problem comes when i'm trying to download the attachments of noreply emails. I can see that this code is at least reading the message by doing a var_dump or print_r of the email array, however it completely ignores the fact that these messages have attachments and does not do anything about it. Its as if the attachments don't exist for the noreply emails, but are clearly there and visible if I log into gmail.

Does anyone have the slightest clue as to why this code would ignore noreply email attachments?

If I forward the noreply email to this address, and it shows up like it came from me as a forward, it sees the attachments just fine. Its something with this noreply address, it acts like its invisible, even marking it as important in gmail does not help.

Ive tried numerous iterations of php classes I have found online to read email attachments, and they all act as if the attachments don't exist.

```
<?
    $host     = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $login    = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    $password = 'xxxxx';

    $inbox = imap_open($host, $login, $password) or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

    $emails     = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');
    /* useful only if the above search is set to 'ALL' */
    $max_emails = 16;

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* if any emails found, iterate through each email */
    if ($emails) {

        $count = 1;

        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);

        /* for every email... */
        foreach ($emails as $email_number) {

            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);

            /* get mail message, not actually used here.
            Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php
            for details on the third parameter.
            */
            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2);

            /* get mail structure */
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

            $attachments = array();

            /* if any attachments found... */
            if (isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {
                    $attachments[$i] = array(
                        'is_attachment' => false,
                        'filename' => '',
                        'name' => '',
                        'attachment' => ''
                    );

                    if ($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                        foreach ($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                            if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['filename']      = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                        foreach ($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                            if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['name']          = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i + 1);

                        /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                        if ($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) {
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                        /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                        elseif ($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) {
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                if ($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1) {
                    $filename = $attachment['name'];
                    if (empty($filename))
                        $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                    if (empty($filename))
                        $filename = time() . ".dat";

                    /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                     * have the attachment with the same file name.
                     */
                    $fp = fopen('./' . $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                    fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                    fclose($fp);

                }

            }

            if ($count++ >= $max_emails)
                break;
        }

    }

    imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

Does php imap ignore noreply emails? Can I do anything about this? Any suggestion, and or help is appreciated.

This is a copy of the "original message" on gmail

```
 Delivered-To: xxxxxx@gmail.com
 Received: by x.x.x.x with SMTP id xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    Thu, 13 Jul 2017 07:37:27 -0700 (PDT)
 X-Received: by x.x.xx.x with SMTP id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    Thu, 13 Jul 2017 07:37:27 -0700 (PDT)
 ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1499956647; cv=none;
    d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
    b=GZYuJrDpYptarZPpUW0/GAIJgDB9cs+EHlVRug/BTaaHE6jobO9/3jBqYaSmpV/wGQ
     KM6X1eVdLgy0cFetmzAxV4d2ocg9oLgpk34Q4WobbU/YqHsu0hN+Qves2+3MDUPW1ohe
     I2ZuDuZWMJEVOLaUoMBvZCr+baUyGsK/Z0RwkkIeLZSJz8KU5Fp7uP0SNOuPzu0L/lgC
     AeWqWWZwjF79YJpQX9+qkml54ARgF8wWkxsyBUy05X7uHN1xPs0/aglCL5Qnpf02Aucx
     26KmRk+2hDtAydlwCdlg8aAwANNsxYoOKmifcJxhzDsHS4bfcxqxLXNrpQqtFG9iEB9p
     U/Sw==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; 
s=arc-20160816;
    h=message-id:subject:date:to:from:mime-version
     :arc-authentication-results;
    bh=ohea4Dm6L7cRDWaoxA4kjgSY+yfMNdq2sByJoPX07W8=;
    b=bESVgQCdCXN4ZVgRcIUX+tymYO/SuSdW7EBg0sIqjcaxhpdaPj29pKM/cv5zpIz8qX
     fy09T7i3tLN+XLGpA+Blk9lR5D511Nd4ra2URGNa2mudkMkVvCQ2X5seild1XC/V3rKf
     /0WJmIfUwYMZ7hUedajiFMF3HmrD37B+pr/+1q4LLuxzdBUkuJQbRCo0WBvsN2FqxeGz
     pr7W8XKYyFRmFJtlrTZ8crANU/W91P23B+YazI8rFD66GGEZ0HGmi5e7WeUWknO02IBz
     F6jvZ0AW+gkZJPS/J+fo0I7T/BR+0xZb8Hs+/UlAa2FxK9u/wUODdG7BlA+vfjEYcBql
     KQYg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   spf=neutral (google.com: x is neither permitted nor denied 
by best guess record for domain of noreply@my.hostednumbers.com) 
smtp.mailfrom=noreply@my.hostednumbers.com
Return-Path: <noreply@my.hostednumbers.com>
Received: from mail1.patlive.local (mail1.patlive.com. [x])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id r10si1078748vkf.224.2017.07.13.07.37.22
    for <xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
    Thu, 13 Jul 2017 07:37:27 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: x is neither permitted nor 
denied by best guess record for domain of noreply@my.hostednumbers.com) 
client-ip=xxxxxxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=neutral (google.com: xxxxx is neither permitted nor denied 
 by best guess record for domain of noreply@my.hostednumbers.com) 
 smtp.mailfrom=noreply@my.hostednumbers.com
 Received: from MTAS2 (1xxxx3) by mail1.patlive.com (1xxxxx1) with 
 Microsoft SMTP Server id 8.3.485.1; Thu, 13 Jul 2017 10:37:21 -0400
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "noreply@my.hostednumbers.com" <noreply@my.hostednumbers.com>
To: xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 10:37:21 -0400
Subject: Your Voice Recording from xxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="--boundary_529647_d1f7373e-194b-
4711-89de-c6cf1f12d209"
Message-ID: <1d5fabae-6801-4146-92bc-782e4338e584@MAIL1.patlive.local>
Return-Path: noreply@my.hostednumbers.com

----boundary_529647_d1f7373e-194b-4711-89de-c6cf1f12d209
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--boundary_529646_c76337af-e5d5-4ccd-a09a-47bde8e77149"

----boundary_529646_c76337af-e5d5-4ccd-a09a-47bde8e77149
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

From:  xxxxxxxx
To:  xxxxxxxxx
Forwarded To:  xxxxxxxxxxx
Date:  Thursday, July 13, 2017 10:37 AM
Recording URL:  xxxxxxxxxxx
----boundary_529646_c76337af-e5d5-4ccd-a09a-47bde8e77149
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
=09<title>Email</title>
=09</head>

<style type=3D"text/css">
=09body
=09{
=09=09margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; color: #585858; font-f=
amily: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; =
font-size: x-small; background:#FFFFFF;
=09}
=09p, b
=09{
=09=09color: #585858;
=09}
=09a:link, a:visited
=09{=09
=09=09color: #3399cc;
=09}
=09a:hover
=09{
=09=09color: #666666;
=09}
=09#bodyText
=09{
=09=09margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width: auto;=
 text-align:left; font-size: 10pt;
=09}
</style>

<body>
=09<div id=3D"bodyText">
=09=09<br><b>From:</b>  xxxxxx
=09=09<br><b>To:</b>  xxxxxxxx
=09=09<br><b>Forwarded To:</b>  xxxxxxxxxx
=09=09<br><b>Date:</b>  Thursday, July 13, 2017 10:37 AM
=09=09<br><b>Recording URL:</b>  <a href="xxxxxx"</a>
=09=09</p>
=09</div>
=09</body>
=09</html>
=09
----boundary_529646_c76337af-e5d5-4ccd-a09a-47bde8e77149--
----boundary_529647_d1f7373e-194b-4711-89de-c6cf1f12d209
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="--boundary_529648_5a6e09fa-c57c-4137-894e-b56991b5674f"

----boundary_529648_5a6e09fa-c57c-4137-894e-b56991b5674f
Content-Type: audio/mp3; name="247195094.mp3"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; read-date="13 Jul 2017 10:37:17 -0400"; modification-date="13 Jul 2017 10:37:16 -0400"; creation-date="13 Jul 2017 10:37:17 -0400"


----boundary_529648_5a6e09fa-c57c-4137-894e-b56991b5674f--
----boundary_529647_d1f7373e-194b-4711-89de-c6cf1f12d209--
```

Im not crazy right? The content type is an audio mp3 and there is in fact an attachment, correct?

This is a screenshot of gmail, looks like an attachment to me....?[image: gmail]

```
    ["attachments"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["section"]=> array(5) {
            [0]=> string(1) "1"
            [1]=> string(3) "1.1"
            [2]=> string(3) "1.2"
            [3]=> string(1) "2"
            [4]=> string(3) "2.1" 
        } 
    ["structure"]=> object(stdClass)#30 (11) {  
        ["type"]=> int(1)
        ["encoding"]=> int(0)
        ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1)
        ["subtype"]=> string(5) "MIXED"
        ["ifdescription"]=> int(0)
        ["ifid"]=> int(0)
        ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0)
        ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0)
        ["ifparameters"]=> int(1)
        ["parameters"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#31 (2) { 
                ["attribute"]=> string(8) "boundary"
                ["value"]=> string(54) "--boundary_542309_d05747ba-05b7-4337-ab17-bdb9f8f827bd" 
            } 
        }
        ["parts"]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#32 (11) { 
                ["type"]=> int(1)
                ["encoding"]=> int(0)
                ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1)
                ["subtype"]=> string(11) "ALTERNATIVE"
                ["ifdescription"]=> int(0)
                ["ifid"]=> int(0)
                ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0)
                ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0)
                ["ifparameters"]=> int(1)
                ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#33 (2) { 
                        ["attribute"]=> string(8) "boundary" 
                        ["value"]=> string(54) "--boundary_542308_68f3d65d-9307-4b78-a641-5c1d89dcdd21" 
                    } 
                } 
                ["parts"]=> array(2) { 
                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#34 (12) { 
                        ["type"]=> int(0) 
                        ["encoding"]=> int(4) 
                        ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                        ["subtype"]=> string(5) "PLAIN" 
                        ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                        ["lines"]=> int(2) 
                        ["bytes"]=> int(251) 
                        ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                        ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#35 (2) { 
                                ["attribute"]=> string(7) "charset" 
                                ["value"]=> string(8) "us-ascii" 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                    [1]=> object(stdClass)#36 (12) { 
                        ["type"]=> int(0) 
                        ["encoding"]=> int(4) 
                        ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                        ["subtype"]=> string(4) "HTML" 
                        ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                        ["lines"]=> int(13) 
                        ["bytes"]=> int(1198) 
                        ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                        ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#37 (2) { 
                                ["attribute"]=> string(7) "charset"
                                ["value"]=> string(8) "us-ascii" 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            [1]=> object(stdClass)#38 (11) { 
                ["type"]=> int(1) 
                ["encoding"]=> int(0) 
                ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                ["subtype"]=> string(5) "MIXED" 
                ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#39 (2) { 
                        ["attribute"]=> string(8) "boundary" 
                        ["value"]=> string(54) "--boundary_542310_9e05358b-ebf4-4c63-b75d-e846238f69aa" 
                    }
                } 
                ["parts"]=> array(1) { 
                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#40 (13) { 
                        ["type"]=> int(4)
                        ["encoding"]=> int(3) 
                        ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                        ["subtype"]=> string(3) "MP3" 
                        ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                        ["bytes"]=> int(8013576) 
                        ["ifdisposition"]=> int(1) 
                        ["disposition"]=> string(10) "attachment" 
                        ["ifdparameters"]=> int(1) 
                        ["dparameters"]=> array(3) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#41 (2) { 
                                ["attribute"]=> string(9) "read-date" 
                                ["value"]=> string(26) "14 Jul 2017 11:21:11 -0400" 
                            } 
                            [1]=> object(stdClass)#42 (2) { 
                                ["attribute"]=> string(17) "modification-date" 
                                ["value"]=> string(26) "14 Jul 2017 11:21:11 -0400" 
                            }
                            [2]=> object(stdClass)#43 (2) { 
                                ["attribute"]=> string(13) "creation-date" 
                                ["value"]=> string(26) "14 Jul 2017 11:21:11 -0400" 
                            } 
                        } 
                        ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                        ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#44 (2) { 
                                ["attribute"]=> string(4) "name" 
                                ["value"]=> string(13) "247206024.mp3" 
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the original headers as well?  (Use get original source from gmail, and then clip the binary data)

Comment: PHP works fine. Either your class is broken or you are doing something wrong. No problems for me with https://github.com/SSilence/php-imap-client

Comment: @Max can you confirm that there are at least attachments it should be seeing? The headers suggest multipart/mixed correct? I've also tried using SSilence/php-imap-client and it returns blank arrays for the attachments. Does this simply mean there are no real attachments?

Comment: I'm worried about the lack of an empty line before the boundary.  It is possible your IMAP server can't interpret the message, although gmail is usually pretty good about that.  Can you get a protocol trace?

Comment: @Max how would i get a protocol trace?

Comment: @Teson Do you have any idea as to why using php-imap-client doing $email->attachments would only show an empty array, when further down you can see the mp3?? See the edited question above for what i am referring to

Comment: @Teson in Structure->parts[1]->parts[0] you can see there is an mp3 that I'm trying to get

Comment: @Teson the original code I have works better at seeing attachments than php-imap-client. I can physically see and save the attachments in the emails with the above original code, where as with php-imap-client the attachments array is always empty

Comment: @mkhimself, might be that the attachment is sent as a sub-attachment for the html-mail.  If I'm right, sending your body with text/plain would populate attachments[].